# Compact and sequentially compact in $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I read that in a metric space compactness and sequential compactness mean the same thing. In $\Bbb R$ is sequential compactness equivalent to compactness? I see some definitions of Heine–Borel theorem use compactness, and others use sequential compactness.

Answer (score 8):

$\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ *are* metric spaces (with metric given by $d(x,y)=\lvert x-y\rvert$).

Comment: You probably mean $||x-y||$ in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @QiL Yes, sort of, though it is not at all uncommon to use the $\lvert\cdot\rvert$ notation even in $\mathbb{R}^n$. It depends on context. Neither notation is clearly wrong.